# Antlr rule for matching filename

Tags: antlr

I am looking for a good way to match a filename in Antlr.

The filename could be DOS or Unix style.

If you have a good solution that to that, feel free to ignore the rest of this question because it is just my newbie attempt at solving the problem and I am probably way off.  I have included it because some people like to see sample code.

For purposes of discussion, here is a here is what I am thinking.  This is not my actual grammar as all I am interested in for this discussion is filename parsing so I reduced the sample that somewhat meaningful in that context.

Lexer.g4:

```
lexer grammar Lexer;
K_COPY : C O P Y ;

FILEPATH: [-.a-zA-Z0-9:/\]+;
```

Parser.g4

```
parser grammar Parser;
options { tokenVocab=Lexer; }

commandfile: (statement NEWLINE)* EOF;

statement : copy_stmt  
      ;

copy_stmt: K_COPY left=filepath right=filepath
     ;

// Add characters as we make rules as to what characters are valid:
filepath: FILEPATH;
```

That is what I am thinking but I am new to Antlr so I wanted to get some feedback before I proceed.

I am using Antlr for this project is already decided and a good part of this project is already working in Antlr, so I am only looking for Antlr based solutions.

Comment: Is that the full grammar? If so, why use such heavy artillery as ANTLR for such a simple task? I strongly suspect you have a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski  I edited the question to address your comment.

Comment: Well, that `filepath` rule would need to be a lexer rule, so you'd need a `FILEPATH` token type (which will have its own issues, such as not working for files named `copy`). Still, using ANTLR for this seems *wrong*. You'd be better off asking what your *real* problem is, you'd probably get some good advice. Until then, people may suggest solutions which will work with this simple example but will be unsuitable in your real code (and that's why I'm writing this as a comment).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks for the suggestion of creating a Lexer rule for FILEPATH.  I have done that.  As for posting my real code: a) My company would not like that, b) Someone else would probably complain that my sample is too big and I should reduce it to something simple.  I am going to keep my simple example.  The problem you pointed out: won't handle files named COPY is an issue.  do you have a solution for that in my simple example?

Comment: Sure, several workarounds are possible (lexer modes, or getting rid of the `K_COPY` token and possibly using predicates to differentiate between commands and file paths (a command is also a file path after all), or extending the built-in lexer, etc etc), but again, I have no clue which solution would be most suitable for your issue, as I don't know what the rest of your grammar looks like.

Comment: Have you tried starting from one of the many regular expressions for file names, e.g. https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/regex-that-matches-path-filename-and-extension/ and create that lexer rule from it?

Comment: @MikeLischke No, I am going to pursue Lucas' suggestion of using predicates.  Then it will only pull in the filename in the context of COPY.